# Detect Heart Rate using iPhone Camera

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, heartbeat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting heart rate using the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274027/detecting-heart-rate-using-the-camera)

I am working on detecting pulse rate in iOS. I have done some search and now I am able to read heart beats using external bluetooth device which is capable of reading heart beats. But now I am ver curious about detecting pulse using iPhone camera. I am trying to understand How it can be done? What is actual theory behind that? Can any one have an idea behind this?

According to my search I found that I need to use camera in video mode. And I need to compare each frames from that video for colour changes. When our heart pumps blood into our body, colours are changed with every pump. So how will I get that colour change using camera or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There is a Symbian app that claims to do just that. I don't think it's reliable.

Comment: Hello. Have you found a solution? I would appreciate if you share it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone at MIT Media Labs beat you to it :P

http://www.cardiio.com/

Click on "How it works".

I believe the gist of it was that the app measures the amount of light reflected off your face due to increase/decrease in blood. Based on this, they can determine your heart rate.

Don't know about the underlying algorithm. If I know, I wouldn't be sitting here, I'd be writing MIT apps :D

Apparently there is a threshold that is considered a "standard" heart rate.

> Studies have shown that our heart rate measurements are within 3 bpm
>   of a clinical pulse oximeter when performed at rest in a well-lit
>   environment (Poh et al., Opt. Express 2010; Poh et al., IEEE Trans
>   Biomed Eng 2011).

You'll probably need some sophisticated equipment to record your results like a real heart rate measure machine so you can compare the RGB (in 255,255,255 triplets values) between different frames at different heart rate and also you have to make sure you're sitting in about the same exact environment with controlled lighting.

If you try to do it at home, you'll get no where. If the sky dims for example, you're going to get different RGBA value.

Comment: It might be easier to track the change in color in your fingertip, neck, or any other pace where the skin is thinner, and the colorchanges are easier to track.

Comment: :P Except someone else already done that too: http://www.azumio.com/apps/heart-rate/

Comment: Yes I know about this. Actually there are so many other applications like cardiio who has done this already. And yes once we will get the algorithm which does this then we can test it with other body parts as well ;0

Comment: Hi guys, Actually from the cardiio app, I understood that we need to detect light change on skin using iPhone's camera. But now I am stuck with colour comparison thing. I am using AVFoundation framework for getting images continuously, but now what should be done on next step is another big question. Any idea or suggestion??

Comment: glReadPixels() :P, I found this with Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144250/how-to-get-the-rgb-values-for-a-pixel-on-an-image-on-the-iphone

Comment: Check out my answer -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274027/detecting-heart-rate-using-the-camera/15653648#15653648

Comment: HI i am also getting this issue , and i achieved the RGB colour of images now i want to calculate heart rate from those RGB colour . please suggest